# Visualforce Remote Objects Returning Empty Objects

Tags: visualforce, security, vf-remote-objects

I've got a remote object query operation that's failing in our managed package in a particular client's org.

Essentially it queries an object with some filters based on the date, and it's returning the correct number of records, so the query is actually working. If I remove all of the parameters it returns all of the records.

What's failing is that all of the records returned are completely empty, as can be seen from my JS console:

```
records[0]._props
Object {  }
```

Has anyone come across this before and got a fix? It's not sharing, and it's not FLS, both have been checked but even if one of those was at fault it wouldn't explain the Id and other system fields being missing.

**More Confusing Info:**

Matt Bingham asked what I get in the `event` parameter to the remote object callback, and it turns out the records property in there contains the record with the values in tact, so now I'm even more confused as to why the records array itself has an empty object. Seems like a platform bug at this point.

Comment: Any chance that they do not have a license to the package? Just thinking out loud, code would find the records but when returning to the VF page they could not see anything......But then again if they did not have a license they would not be on the page correct....Can you explain the flow a bit more?

Comment: License is good, other remoting & remote objects requests on the page are working perfectly fine.

Comment: May be dumb.. is the code running in user context who do not have permissions on the object?

Comment: Nope, user is admin and I've checked the profile twice. I can see the records if I query from the dev console etc.